# Packaging java applicaition in Windows 10, open JDK 11

Tags: java, jlink, openjdk-11, javapackager

I am migrating my development environment from a PC with Windows 7 to one with Windows 10.

I can no longer run the packaging to create the executable bundle. The error I get is the following:

> Bundler Windows Application Image skipped because of a configuration problem: This copy of the JDK does not support Windows.

I'm using

```
call "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" ^
    -Xmx1024M ^
    --module-path "%JAVA_HOME%\jmods" ^
    --add-opens jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.packager=jdk.packager ^
    -m jdk.packager/jdk.packager.Main ^
    create-image ^
    --verbose ^
    --echo-mode ^
    --input "%INPUT%" ^
    --main-jar "%JAR%" ^
    --output "%OUTPUT%" ^
    --name "Name" ^
    --icon "%ICON%"
```

Have any idea?

Comment: If you execute `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version` what is the output ?

Comment: Please show what the command looks like with variables expanded.  Replacing "call" with "echo" is one way to do it.

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)